# Trying to install League of legends on play on linux but crashes when i attempt to install

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Running On linux verson

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Hello I have been trying to install League on play on linux but no matter what I do I always crash the wizard. I am fairly new to linux so be sure to ask if i missed anything. This crash happens immediately after I hit North America then next.

Here is the crash log:

```
Error in POL_System_wget
POL_System_wget failed: Server issued an error response
--2017-05-21 11:09:01-- http://l3cdn.riotgames.com/Installer/SingleFileInstall/LeagueOfLegendsBaseNA.exe
Resolving l3cdn.riotgames.com (l3cdn.riotgames.com)... 209.197.3.7
Connecting to l3cdn.riotgames.com (l3cdn.riotgames.com)|209.197.3.7|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-05-21 11:09:02 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Comment: It looks like problem with LOL server, try another location

Comment: PoL must update their link. That's an old link and it's no longer working. The new link is https://riotgamespatcher-a.akamaihd.net/ShellInstaller/NA/LeagueofLegends_NA_Installer_2016_05_13.exe

Comment: what do i do with this file?

Answer (score 0):

`error 403` is a response from the web server at `l3cdn.riotgames.com` saying that it will not let you access the file you're trying to access ("Access forbidden"). It's a server-side decision. See [the Wikipedia entry on Error 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the POL install doesn't result in a playable LoL setup without further tweaking. I would recommend searching for recent guide to install LoL on Ubuntu, for example here: [reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/)